# Child element styling CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I have a div with the id = Body and inside this div i have another div with the id = TableWrapper_Wrapper witch acts as a table for jQuery datatables.

I would like to apply styling to this table.

In my CSS file i have styling added to the body div which works and styling for the TableWrapper_Wrapper which does not work.

```
body 
{
    font-size: 100%;
    background:#F1F1F1;
}

TableWrapper_wrapper
{
    font-size: 12px;
    white-space: nowrap;   
}
```

Below is a screen shot of the consloe so you can see the name of the table.

[image]

Could someone please tell me how i could add some styling to this table.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TableWrapper_wrapper` is the id of a div, so you need to use the [id-selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#id-selectors) (prefix `#` to the id` - read about [css selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)

```
#TableWrapper_wrapper
{
    font-size: 12px;
    white-space: nowrap;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
#TableWrapper_wrapper
{
    font-size: 12px;
    white-space: nowrap;   
}
```

Because `TableWrapper_Wrapper` is an `id` not an `tag`.You can also style them using `classname` with `TableTables_wrapper` like

```
.TableTables_wrapper
{
    font-size: 12px;
    white-space: nowrap;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you not to use keywords like body as an id of any other tag.
and the styling you given

```
body 
{
    font-size: 100%;
    background:#F1F1F1;
}
```

in stylesheet if you call body without '#' or '.', it will be considered as body tag

```
<body></body>
```

, and the style you write there apply  to whole body.. 
thats why your style is working. and

```
TableWrapper_wrapper
{
    font-size: 12px;
    white-space: nowrap;   
}
```

this is not the method to call an id, use hash prefix like this. '#TableWrapper_wrapper'.

```
#TableWrapper_wrapper
    {
        font-size: 12px;
        white-space: nowrap;   
    }
```

and for classes use dot prefix, like this '.TableWrapper_wrapper'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put '#' as for ID selector in CSS. And body tag is already in html structure so no need to use body as a id.
you can try below code

```
body {font-size: 100%; background:#F1F1F1;} 
#TableWrapper_wrapper{font-size: 12px; white-space: nowrap; }
```